# Installing guest additions on Virtualbox 4.10 - Host: openSUSE 11.3 64 bit, Guest: Slackware 13.37 32 bit

Tags: opensuse, virtualbox

The `Devices menu` -> `CD/DVD Devices` contains `VBoxGuestAdditions.iso`
**But ticking the above menu option doesn't show any menu to select anything from.**

The `kernel-devel` is already there.
The host is `openSUSE 11.3` 64 bit. The guest is `Slackware 13.37` 32 bit.

What's the way round now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you have mounted the iso on the host (looks like you have done this part) login to the guest console, mount the CDROM and run the installer (this is inside the guest)

Comment: No prob. I am a virtual junkie!

Answer (score 3):

Guest: **Slackware 13.37**

Open the terminal in the guest Linux OS, and then type:

```
su  
mount /dev/sr0 /mnt/cdrom  
cd /mnt/cdrom  
ls  
./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```